# TaskbarIcon wpf error in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, taskbar

I am doing a MenuItem with TaskbarIcon, and I need some item enable and some disable. So I do this:

```
  <MenuItem Header="Open" Visibility="true"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Settings" Visibility="true"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close" Visibility="true"/>

                <MenuItem Header="Desconnect" Visibility="false" />
                <MenuItem Header="Show status" Visibility="false" />
                <MenuItem Header="Show logs" Visibility="false" />
                <MenuItem Header="Show servers" Visibility="false" />
                <MenuItem Header="Settings" Visibility="false" />
                <MenuItem Header="Close" Visibility="false" />
```

But I obtain a wrong menu, like this picture: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s9Ys.png)

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this...`<MenuItem Header="Close" IsEnabled = "false" />`

Comment: no, I tried, but not.

Comment: Visibility is not a flag based dependency property. It contains three available choises visible, collapsed and hidden. To fix issue you're having you should use collapsed.

Comment: Perfect! Collapsed works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visibility is not a flag based dependency property. It contains three available (`enum`) choises `Visible`, `Collapsed` and `Hidden`. To fix issue you're having you should use `Collapsed`.

`Hidden` just hides control which is marked with this property, but size that it occupy is still presisted. That is the reason you are experiencing issue shown in the picture.

`Collapsed` you can call it removes item your view completely without any visible trace.

For more information refer [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx)